# Resharper memory usage in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

Can you suggest some ways/tips to decrease Resharper memory usage in VS 2008. Working set memory for my VS with 50 projects is around 650mb+

**Edit:** Now that 4.5 is out, this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: You're lucky I get almost the same amount of memory with two (theoretically) not code bloated projects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a completely unreasonable amount of memory when you've got *50* projects, Do they really all need to be in the same solution? If so, can you not just get more memory? While there may be ways of decreasing the R# memory use (disable its code analysis?) I suspect it won't make *that* much difference. I suspect in the end you'll have to accept that a modern IDE with a massive solution requires a powerful machine.

Answer (score 10):

650mb+ isn't abnormal, i have solution with 15 projects and 1k files and VS+ReSharper use 500mb (only ReSharper use 153mb)

Try this for show how much memory ReSharper use
ReSharper -> Options -> General -> Show managed memory usage in status bar